# What's the difference between CADisplayLink's displayLinkWithTarget:selector: and UIScreen's displayLinkWithTarget:selector:?

Tags: ios, cadisplaylink

CADisplayLink having this method makes sense, but I'm curious why UIScreen would also have it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Documentation says that the display link provided by the screen is tied to that screen. However, looking at the official documentation, there is no apparent relation to any screens; the display link is added to a runloop and that's it.

Digging [deeper in the private headers](https://github.com/nst/iOS-Runtime-Headers/blob/master/Frameworks/QuartzCore.framework/CADisplayLink.h#L9), there is a `display` property, of type [`CADisplay`](https://github.com/nst/iOS-Runtime-Headers/blob/master/Frameworks/QuartzCore.framework/CADisplay.h), which is [also found for `UIScreen`](https://github.com/nst/iOS-Runtime-Headers/blob/master/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/UIScreen.h#L21). So it seems, that indeed, you can create display links specific to screens. Normally on iOS and tvOS, there is only one screen, but that is not always the case (such as connecting a monitor to an iOS device). If your app supports external monitors, and you find the need to use a display link, you should use the `-[UIScreen displayLinkWithTarget:selector:]` method.

Consider opening a bug report with Apple with a documentation enhancement request to clarify the above behavior.

Comment: The comment above the method in `CADisplayLink.h` does specify that it creates a new display link object "for the main display" which is the display for `[UIScreen mainScreen]`.  Apple likes putting useful information in the header files and leaving it out of the documentation for some reason.